# Inequality derived Schwarz's Lemma

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $U(0,R)$ with $0< R.$ Assume there exists an $M > 0$ such that $|f(z)| \leq M$ for $z \in U(0,R)$ and an $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ satisfying $$0 = f(0) = f'(0) = ... = f^{(n)}(0).$$
Show that $$|f(z)| \leq M(\frac{|z|}{R})^{n+1}$$ for all $z \in U(0,R)$, and $$\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(0)|}{(n+1)!} \leq \frac{M}{R^{n+1}}.$$

I think I should use Schwarz's Lemma to show it. Since $f$ is holomorphic on $U(0,R)$, then $$f(z) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kz^k = \sum_{k = n+1}^\infty a_kz^k$$ for $z \in U(0,R)$ (because $f^{(j)}(0) = 0$ for $ 0 \leq j \leq n)$.

Set $g : U(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, $$g(\frac{z}{R}) = \frac{R^nf(z)}{z^nM} =\frac{R^n}{M} \sum_{k= n+1}^\infty a_kz^{n-k}.$$ Notice that $g$ is holomorphic on $U(0,1)$ and $g(0) = 0.$ If I can show that $|g(\frac{z}{R})| < 1 $ for $z \in U(0,R)$, I can apply Schwarz 's Lemma and the result will be immediate. But I cannot show that $|g(\frac{z}{R})| < 1$ for $z \in U(0,R)$. Can anyone give a hint ? Is my approach suitable ?

Comment: What is $U(0,R)$?

Comment: It is the open ball centered at $0$ with radius $R$, $U(0,R) = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \ | |z| < R\}.$

Answer (score 1):

$f$ has a zero of multiplicity at least $n+1$ in $0$. Thus, $g$ holomorphic with with $f(z) = z^{n+1}g(z)$ exists. By maximum principle we have $|g(z)| = \left|\frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}\right| \leq \frac{M}{R^{n+1}}$ for all $z\in U(0,R)$.

Hence $|f(z)| \leq M\frac{|z^{n+1}|}{R^{n+1}}$ for all $z\in U(0,R)$.

Comment: So you assume that at least $a_{n+1}$ is not zero, right ? Does the condition on $g$ need to be holomorphic and $g(0)\neq0$.

Comment: No, we don't need to assume that. And we don't need $g(0) \neq 0$ aswell. Why should we?

Comment: okay, I see. So It is needed just $g$ is holomorphic. Since $g$ is continuous on the compact set cl $(0,R)$, its modulus attain maximum. But we do not know that $g$ is nonconstant yet. I guess that the existence of $n$ with indentity principle prevent $f$ from being a constant on $U(0,R)$. Then $g$ cannot be a constant. So modulus of $g$ attain maximum on $\partial U(0,R)$, and I have the inequality. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: If $g$ was constant then $f$ is constant. Since $f(0) = 0$, the statement is trivial then.

Comment: There is a new problem now. There is another question concerning the result of this question : Assume either  there exists $c$ with $0 < |c| < R$ making the inequality become equality or the second inequality concerning the $(n+1)$ derivative become equality, then there must exist $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| = 1$ such that $$f(z) = \alpha \frac{M |z|^{n+1}}{R^{n+1}}.$$ I firstly assume that $f$ satisfies Schwarz ' s Lemma which will be immediately provide the $\alpha.$ But now if I show the first problem by Maximum Modulus Principle, then I have to find new way to prove equality case. ??????

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f(Rz)/M$ maps the unit disc to itself, since $f(Rz) \leqslant M$ for $0<\lvert z \rvert < 1$.

Define
$$ g(z) = \begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{M} \frac{f(Rz)}{z^{n+1}} & z \neq 0 \\
\frac{R^{n+1}}{M}\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{(n+1)!} & z=0
\end{cases},  $$
and now the proof goes in the same way as Schwarz's lemma: By the conditions in the question, $g$ is analytic on $U(0,1)$, (obviously you need to check this at $0$: use the Taylor series) so the maximum principle applies. On the boundary, $g(z) \leqslant 1$, so we find that for $0 < \lvert z \rvert \leqslant 1$,
$$ \frac{1}{M} \frac{f(Rz)}{z^{n+1}} \leqslant 1, $$
which gives the right answer after untangling the substitution. Further, what does this give at $z=0$? Why,
$$ \frac{R^{n+1}}{M}\frac{f^{(n+1)}(0)}{(n+1)!} \leqslant 1, $$
which is the other thing we wanted.

---

The second part can also be done using the Cauchy Integral formula:
$$ f^{(n+1)}(0) = \frac{(n+1)!}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+2}} \, dz, $$
by using the trivial inequality $\int_{\gamma} h(z) \, dz < l(\gamma) \max_{\gamma} \lvert h(z) \rvert $, where $l(\gamma)$ is the length of $\gamma$, and then taking $r \to R$ (note you have to do this because the function is not known to be holomorphic on the boundary, so you can't just integrate round that directly). However, given the form of the question, the first method is probably the one required.

Comment: I will try to understand your suggestion and fill all the gaps in the proof. Thank you very much !!! If I need further assistance, I will ask later.